# Label not showing previous text, showing just the updated text

Tags: java, label

The problem I'm having with this program is that, at first I want the label to show system date, wait for 5 seconds and then show "hi", however on running the code, the label just shows "hi". Please help me find my mistake.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class DigClock
{

public static void main(String a[])
{
    try
    {
        JFrame f= new JFrame();
        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        JLabel l=new JLabel((new Date()).toString());
        p.add(l);
        f.add(p);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        l.setText("hi");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because your thread sleeps for 5sec before your frame is set visible? Your could try swapping the Thread.sleep line with the f.setvisible line. Can't try it myself right now because I'm away of my PC :)

Answer (score 0):

a simple mistake...You write the

```
 thread.sleep
```

before the form visibility,At that sleeping time your page visibility is false and you cannot see the page. That means you can get the page opened after 5 seconds.After five seconds the label is already changed.

copy this code

```
    public class DigClock {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            try
        {
            JFrame f= new JFrame();
            JPanel p=new JPanel();
            JLabel l=new JLabel((new Date()).toString());
            p.add(l);
            f.add(p);

            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            l.setText("hi");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
        }
    }
```

Regds..